# struts2 form submit not hitting method

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a .jsp form like so

```
<s:form action="AuditLogReport">Source IP<br>
<input type="text" class="auditLogSearch" name="sourceIp" value="All">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</s:form>
```

And my struts.xml is defined

```
    <action name="AuditLogReport" 
    class="com.mycom.selfservice.actions.AuditLogAction" method="auditLogReport">  
                <result name="success">jsp/AuditLog.jsp</result> 
                <result name="error">jsp/Error.jsp</result>  
    </action>
```

Here is my class definition

```
public class AuditLogAction extends ActionSupport implements Action,ServletRequestAware {
```

And in my AuditLogAction class there is a method

```
public String auditLogReport() {
    System.out.println("Im in auditLogReport...");
```

but when I click the button, auditLogReport method does not get hit.  What I see in the browser url is `http://localhost:7001/BPSelfServicePortal/AuditLogReport.action`

It is appending .action which I think is why it doesn't find the method.  So I tried putting

```
 <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>
```

in the struts.xml.  That prevented the .action from being appended but the button still didn't work.  Plus it caused the .css and images from being found.  I have a link that uses the default execute() method and that works ok.

If I simply remove the .action in the url and hit enter, it hits the method but then none of the values in the form get passed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a Date parameter.  Apparently struts2 doesn't like them.

```
public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}
public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}
```

Changed it to

```
public String getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}
public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}
```

And then it worked!